# How to Wrap Numbers in bootstrap table?

Tags: css, jsp, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-table

Using bootstrap table we are displaying content from DB, generally this data's are huge in text size. So for all the headers we have given some fixed width like below,

```
<th width="100px">Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text </>
```

**Sample wrapping text,**

[image]

When the text is greater than the allocated width then it wrapped into next line with proper alignment. But same logic couldn't work for non-spaced numbers like below,

```
<th width="100px">1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@</>
```

**Sample Non-wrapping Numbers,**

[image]

In above screenshot, the numbers are just overlapping to next column. How to make it wrap from the fixed width?

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `width` attribute of a `td` accepts unitless values. Also, please use CSS for dimensions.

Comment: @Kyle `width` attribute accepts units like `px` or `%`. But if not provided any unit means it will be considered as `px`. However this attribute is now deprecated.

Comment: Yes, that's actually true. I remembered it wrong as I never used to use px or % in the attribute. Definitely deprecated. I'm going to stop commenting before I've had my 3rd coffee of the day ;)

Comment: @Kyle cheers..!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word` to wrap text.

```
th {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```css
th {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@1234567890@</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, let me check on this.

Comment: It helps., Thanks.!!